# Why a class can see the private members of a parameter class?

Tags: c++

Note that class x and y are two separate entities and you can not see their private data members from outside of their bodies.

It is known that from int main() I can not see the private member of class x or y.

My question in the following code in line 22:

Why class x can see the private members of class y ? (note here I am sending class y as reference not as a copy) isn't the referenced class y should be protected from strangers like class x ?

Note that the function getForeignNumber(const Player &r) inside class x is not a friend to class y!

```
#include<iostream>

class Account{
private:
    int number{ } ;
    
public:

Account(int numberValue)
:number{numberValue}
{
    std::cout<<"constructor is called"<<std::endl;
}

int getLocalNumber()
{
    return this->number;
}

int getForeignNumber(const Account &r)
{
    return r.number; // line 22
}
    
};

int main()
{
    Account x{1};
    Account y{2};
    
    std::cout<<"get local number="<<x.getLocalNumber()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"get foreign number x ="<<x.getForeignNumber(x)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"get foreign number y="<<y.getForeignNumber(y)<<std::endl;
    
    
    std::cout<<"Hello world"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How could a class be copied if its copy c'tor couldn't access those? Assignment? Why stop there? Is it *really* a stranger?

Comment: try `cout<<x.number;` you will see what `private` is used for. i.e. try to compile it. The error message would be `error: 'number' is a private member of 'Account'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you are confusing instances of a class with the class. `x` and `y` are two instances of the same class `Account`.

Your analogy isnt sound. Two instances of the same class aren't "strangers". They can access all the internals of each other. Thats how access works.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access):

> All members of a class (bodies of member functions, initializers of member objects, and the entire nested class definitions) have access to all names the class can access. A local class within a member function has access to all names the member function can access.

In other words, access is per class not per instance. If `x` would not be able to access `y`s private members it would be impossible for example to write a copy constructor (without getter methods, which would be silly).

PS: By the way, "see" is the wrong word. There are certain circumstances where you can "see" that there is a private member from outside of the class, you just cannot access it. One such situation is when the name of a private method shadows that of a publicly inherited method https://godbolt.org/z/Kzf5KWv4W. Hence, even colloquially "see" is the wrong word for access.

Comment: Couldn't do move semantics either, without even more verbosity.

Answer (score 1):

The function `getForeignNumber()` can see private members of class `Account` because `getForeignNumber()` is a member of class `Account`.

`private` members are hidden from entities that are outside the class, not from other instances (objects) of the same class.